# Error: <ieeefp.h> not found when building inkscape

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, build, inkscape

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`.

I've downloaded the source code with the command:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape.git
```

Then, installed the dependencies as mentioned in `INSTALL.md`:

> For common linux-distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora) you can use [a
> bash-script](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape-ci-docker/-/raw/master/install_dependencies.sh?inline=false)
> for getting required libaries.

Then, created a folder called `build`:

```
cd inksape
mkdir build
```

Then:

```
cd build
sudo cmake ..
```

What I get:

```
------------------------------
Building Makefile for Inkscape
------------------------------
Source Dir: /home/osama/inkscape
Binary Dir: /home/osama/inkscape/build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Creating build files in: /home/osama/inkscape/build
-- Performing Test LIBATOMIC_NOT_NEEDED
-- Performing Test LIBATOMIC_NOT_NEEDED - Success
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for modules 'harfbuzz;pangocairo;pangoft2;fontconfig;gsl;gmodule-2.0;libsoup-2.4>=2.42;bdw-gc;lcms2'
--   Found harfbuzz, version 2.6.4
--   Found pangocairo, version 1.44.7
--   Found pangoft2, version 1.44.7
--   Found fontconfig, version 2.13.1
--   Found gsl, version 2.5
--   Found gmodule-2.0, version 2.64.6
--   Found libsoup-2.4, version 2.70.0
--   Found bdw-gc, version 7.6.4
--   Found lcms2, version 2.9
-- Found DoubleConversion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so  
-- Performing Test Iconv_IS_BUILT_IN
-- Performing Test Iconv_IS_BUILT_IN - Success
-- Found Iconv: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so  
-- Found Intl: /usr/include  
-- lib2geom not found, using internal copy in src/3rdparty/2geom
-- Checking for module 'poppler'
--   Found poppler, version 0.86.1
-- Found poppler: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so
-- Checking for module 'poppler-glib'
--   Found poppler-glib, version 0.86.1
-- Found poppler-glib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-glib.so
-- Checking for module 'cairo-svg'
--   Found cairo-svg, version 1.16.0
-- Found cairo-svg: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so
-- Checking for module 'poppler-cairo'
--   Found poppler-cairo, version 0.86.1
-- Found poppler-cairo: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so
-- Checking for modules 'libwpg-0.3;librevenge-0.0;librevenge-stream-0.0'
--   Found libwpg-0.3, version 0.3.3
--   Found librevenge-0.0, version 0.0.4
--   Found librevenge-stream-0.0, version 0.0.4
-- Checking for modules 'libvisio-0.1;librevenge-0.0;librevenge-stream-0.0'
--   Found libvisio-0.1, version 0.1.7
--   Found librevenge-0.0, version 0.0.4
--   Found librevenge-stream-0.0, version 0.0.4
-- Checking for modules 'libcdr-0.1;librevenge-0.0;librevenge-stream-0.0'
--   Found libcdr-0.1, version 0.1.6
--   Found librevenge-0.0, version 0.0.4
--   Found librevenge-stream-0.0, version 0.0.4
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.37") 
-- Found Potrace: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpotrace.so
-- Checking for modules 'gtkmm-3.0>=3.24;gdkmm-3.0>=3.24;gtk+-3.0>=3.24;gdk-3.0>=3.24'
--   Found gtkmm-3.0, version 3.24.2
--   Found gdkmm-3.0, version 3.24.2
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.20
--   Found gdk-3.0, version 3.24.20
-- Checking for module 'gspell-1'
--   Found gspell-1, version 1.8.3
-- Using gspell
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.71.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.71.0", minimum required is "1.19.0") found components: filesystem 
-- Found LibXslt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so (found version "1.1.34") 
-- Found LibXml2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so (found version "2.9.10") 
-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")  
-- Checking for module 'readline'
--   Found readline, version 8.0
-- Found GNU Readline: 
-- Checking for module 'ImageMagick++<=7'
--   Found ImageMagick++, version 6.9.10
-- Found Gettext: /usr/bin/msgmerge (found version "0.19.8.1") 
-- Found gettext + msgfmt to convert language files. Translation enabled
-- Found xgettext. inkscape.pot will be re-created if missing.
-- Checking for module 'sigc++-2.0'
--   Found sigc++-2.0, version 2.10.2
-- Found X11: /usr/include   
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE
-- Looking for IceConnectionNumber in ICE - found
-- Creating build files in: /home/osama/inkscape/build
-- Looking for include file ieeefp.h
-- Looking for include file ieeefp.h - not found
-- Looking for mallinfo
-- Looking for mallinfo - found
-- Looking for include file malloc.h
-- Looking for include file malloc.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_FORDBLKS
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_FORDBLKS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_FSMBLKS
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_FSMBLKS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_HBLKHD
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_HBLKHD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_UORDBLKS
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_UORDBLKS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_USMBLKS
-- Performing Test HAVE_STRUCT_MALLINFO_USMBLKS - Success
-- Looking for sincos
-- Looking for sincos - found
-- Generating header and sourcefiles from sp-marshal.list (Glib-Marshal)
INFO: Reading /home/osama/inkscape/src/helper/sp-marshal.list...
INFO: Reading /home/osama/inkscape/src/helper/sp-marshal.list...
-- sp-marshal.h changed; overwriting
CMake Error at src/3rdparty/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /home/osama/inkscape/src/3rdparty/2geom

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


-- Found GTest: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtest.a  
-- Creating link '/home/osama/inkscape/build/inkscape_datadir/inkscape' --> '/home/osama/inkscape/share'
INKSCAPE_DIST_PREFIX: inkscape-1.1-alpha_2021-03-19_eb24388f17
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration Summary
------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT_NAME:            inkscape
INKSCAPE_VERSION:        1.1-alpha
INKSCAPE_DIST_PREFIX:    inkscape-1.1-alpha_2021-03-19_eb24388f17

CMAKE_BINARY_DIR:        /home/osama/inkscape/build
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:    /usr/local
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:    lib
PACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR       share/locale
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:       Linux
CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:    5.8.0-45-generic
CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:  x86_64
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:        /usr/bin/cc
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:      /usr/bin/c++
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:        Release

ENABLE_LCMS:             ON
ENABLE_POPPLER:          ON
ENABLE_POPPLER_CAIRO:    ON
WITH_GNU_READLINE:       ON
WITH_DBUS:               OFF
WITH_GSPELL:             ON
WITH_IMAGE_MAGICK:       ON
WITH_GRAPHICS_MAGICK:    OFF
WITH_LIBCDR:             ON
WITH_LIBVISIO:           ON
WITH_LIBWPG:             ON
WITH_NLS:                ON
WITH_OPENMP:             ON
WITH_JEMALLOC:           OFF
WITH_INTERNAL_2GEOM:     ON
WITH_PROFILING:          OFF
BUILD_TESTING:           ON
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

`CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`:

```
Determining if files ieeefp.h exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_1eb11/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/HAVE_IEEEFP_H.c.o
/usr/bin/cc  -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/libsoup-2.4 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/poppler -I/usr/include/libwpg-0.3 -I/usr/include/libwpd-0.10 -I/usr/include/librevenge-0.0 -I/usr/include/libvisio-0.1 -I/usr/include/libcdr-0.1 -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gspell-1 -I/usr/include/enchant-2 -I/usr/include/readline -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6  -fopenmp    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/HAVE_IEEEFP_H.c.o   -c /home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_IEEEFP_H.c
/home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CheckIncludeFiles/HAVE_IEEEFP_H.c:2:10: fatal error: ieeefp.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <ieeefp.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_1eb11.dir/HAVE_IEEEFP_H.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/osama/inkscape/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_1eb11/fast] Error 2


Source:
/* */
#include <ieeefp.h>


int main(void){return 0;}
```

`CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log`:

Since it's quite long and can't fit in the body of the question, the output is [here](https://pastebin.com/qSqShUAh).

---

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: Any particular reason you're trying to build inkscape yourself, instead of typing in a single command, and having a fully-built, fully-configured inkscape package installed directly from Ubuntu's package repository, ready to run?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes. I'm trying to contribute to the project. I can't contribute if I can't get it to build.

Comment: Then you can simply go download the Ubuntu source package, and see how it gets built on Ubuntu? It's entirely possible that Ubuntu's native build of inkscape includes some patches that are needed to compile it. Or, alternatively, Ubuntu's package building script for inkscape will show which specific configuration and compilation steps are needed to build this package on Ubuntu.

Comment: The first step in [INSTALL.md](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/INSTALL.md) is cloning the project with `--recurse-submodules` option. It seems you failed with this step, as you don't have a directory `2geom` under [src/3rdparty](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/tree/master/src/3rdparty). And CMake error is exactly about this directory: ``The source directory /home/osama/inkscape/src/3rdparty/2geom does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.``

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks alot! this's solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this part in `INSTALL.md`:

> Make sure you got the submodules code when fetching the code (either
> by using --recurse-submodules on the git clone command, as recommended
> on the Getting started page, or by running git submodule init && git
> submodule update)

Comment: The missing part was the `2geom` library under `src/3rdparty/`

Answer (score 0):

There is a particular section in the [inkskape documentation about your question](https://inkscape.org/develop/getting-started/#install-build-dependencies)

The major steps:

```
wget -v https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape-ci-docker/-/raw/master/install_dependencies.sh -O install_dependencies.sh
bash install_dependencies.sh --recommended
```

and than:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PWD}/install_dir -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
make -j8
make install
```

It is common for open source software having to issue different flags during compilation. *(the 8 in -j8 is the number of the cores in your laptop. with 4 cores it would be -j4 with 16 it would be -j16)*

That is one of the reasons the `sudo apt-get install inkskape` command has been invented for the user to spare the hustle.

If that doesn't work it is a bug.

You will find further help for development only in the [irc/matrix chatrooms](https://netsplit.de/channels/?chat=inkscape) Most open source projects have an irc/freenode chatroom for development

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, these extra arguments to `cmake` don't solve the problem. as mentioned in the documentation, the first one is to specify a custom isolated installation location, while the next 3 arguments are for speeding up the process.

Comment: You are right, overlooked it, in that case it is a bug in the installation script and you need to report a bug for the documentation.

Comment: @StackExchange123 Here would be a manual way without the bash script. Was a hustle to make the kde framework compile.

https://linuxcursor.com/linux/how-to-compile-inkscape-from-source

Also there are irc / matrix chatrooms for open source projects: https://inkscape.org/*board/

That is a bit hidden to keep user questions out. I am sure they can help you get further in development. Maybe some of your first contributions might be a proper compiile script? Have fun, don't get frustrated