# Installing / Building the newest version of Inkscape (v 1.2) on Linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-20.04, inkscape, beta

I am trying to install Inkscape 1.2beta on Linux Ubuntu 20.04. The website currently only offers an AppImage and a source tarball. Since I would like to access the newest features of Inkscape via the command line, I need to build and install the source tarball.

INSTALL.md states that I need all submodules and dependencies before install.

How do I find these dependencies to successfully build and install Inkscape?

Comment: INSTALL.md further states that a git clone with the option --recurse-submodules takes care of this, but this does not work for me.

Comment: [INSTALL.md](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/INSTALL.md) states that "For common linux-distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora) you can use
a bash-script for getting required libraries.". Have you tried to use that script? There is also a wiki page containing dependencies: https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Tracking_Dependencies.

Comment: The Tracking Dependencies of the wiki did not help me, since there is no information on how to install them on Linux. I seem to have overlooked the bash-script, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details on how to build Inkscape (and the dependencies) could be found in the [repository](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/) itself, or [Inkscape website](https://inkscape.org/develop/getting-started/) (For completness, the steps are copied from the website here):

- To obtain the latest source code, use the following command (downloads into a subdirectory of your current working directory called "inkscape" by default):

```sh
git clone --recurse-submodules https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape.git
```

To update this code later, change into the download folder and use:

```sh
git pull --recurse-submodules && git submodule update
```

By default, git will download every branch and every commit. If you are on a slow machine, have limited disk space, or limited internet bandwidth, you can use shallow clone and single branch clone options to limit the amount of data it will download:

```
git clone --depth=1 --single-branch --recurse-submodules --shallow-submodule https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape.git
```

### Building Inkscape on Linux

Open a terminal at the root of the folder into which you downloaded the source code in the previous step.

#### Install build dependencies

Download and run the script to install everything required for compiling Inkscape (check script to see if your distribution is supported):

```
wget -v https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape-ci-docker/-/raw/master/install_dependencies.sh -O install_dependencies.sh
bash install_dependencies.sh --recommended
```

#### Compile

To compile with CMake, do the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${PWD}/install_dir -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache
make -j8
make install
```

Notes:

- Using `ccache` is optional but speeds up compilation.
- The optional `-j8` argument to make tells it to run 8 jobs in parallel. Feel free to adjust this to the number of hardware threads (physical cores) available on your computer.
- The recommended `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` argument allows to specify a custom isolated installation location (in the example above `install_dir/` inside the build folder). It avoids installation into system locations (where it could conflict with other versions of Inkscape) and allows running multiple versions of Inkscape in parallel. It will still use all the files (including the `preferences.xml`) that reside in the `~/.config/inkscape` directory.

#### Run

Run it from the build directory:

```
install_dir/bin/inkscape
```

Comment: I followed your procedure from above -  including the bash script to install required dependencies - but the "make" command terminated with an error. Something about lib2geom library not being a shared object. I then found the package lib2geom-dev, and installed it with aptitude. I just rerun your procedure, and got the build running.

Comment: Somehow the bash script does *not* install all required dependencies? I posted the list of aptitude packages that were necessary for my build to work as another answer.

Comment: @conpertura: If you need some length discussion about that, you can use: https://chat.inkscape.org (use the dev channel).

Comment: Went there, and got more information on changes between different builds of inkscape. My initial question was solved by installing the aptitude packages included in the above list on Ubuntu / Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This list should satisfy all required dependencies on Linux Ubuntu:

```
apt install

cmake

imagemagick
libdouble-conversion-dev
libgdl-3-dev
libagg-dev
libpotrace-dev
libboost-all-dev
libsoup2.4-dev
libgc-dev
libwpg-dev
poppler-utils
libpoppler-dev
libpoppler-glib-dev
libpoppler-private-dev
libvisio-dev libvisio-tools
libcdr-dev
libgtkmm-3.0-dev
libgspell-1-dev
libxslt-dev libxslt1-dev
libreadline6-dev
lib2geom-dev
```

lib2geom-dev is needed to solve [error "<ieeefp.h> not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66714087/error-ieeefp-h-not-found-when-building-inkscape).

For building Inkscape:

Download source tarball for Inkscape v1.2 from inkscape.org and extract

```
cd <extracted inkscape directory>
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

If you still get an error during cmake .., please comment below with the names of the missing modules in the error message.